# Remove numpy installed using pip on OS X

Tags: numpy, pip, easy-install

I have two versions of numpy installed on my OS X. One is version 1.2.1 installed via `pip`, the other is the version 1.6.1 installed via `easy_install`.

Now, I would like to remove the older version using `pip uninstall` command. But would that affect the newer version installed by `easy_install`? If so, how should I perserve the newer version while removing the older one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` and `easy_install` use different methods to keep track of modules they install.  Therefore, running `pip uninstall numpy` *shouldn't* affect your newer version installed through `easy_install`.

Of course, this is assuming that they aren't installed in the same directories (although I don't see why or how they could be).